# I don't know what I have to do in order to make (2) work.. in swift

Tags: swift

I want to make things like this.

(1). if I press one of that button(A) among 31. that number(A) turn red.

(2). then if I press another button(B) then (A) turn black again and then (B) turn red.

**

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var collectionViewCell = CollectionViewCell()
let data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier : "MyCell")
}

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.Label.text = String(data[indexPath.row])
        return cell
}
```

}

```
  class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if Label.textColor == .red{
     Label.textColor = .black
    } else if Label.textColor == .black{
     Label.textColor = .red
    }
}

public override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `isSelected` and `func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {`

But first you need to know that in Swift we use camelCase styling for variables.

Now we would have to change a little bit your cell implementation:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    public override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        if selected {
            label.textColor = .red
        } else {
            label.textColor = .black
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
       self.isSelected = !self.isSelected
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to update `cell.Label.text = String(data[indexPath.row])` to `cell.label.text = String(data[indexPath.row])`

**EDIT**

As [Leo Darbus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus) pointed out it would be better to use `isSelected.toggle()` than `self.isSelected = !self.isSelected`, since it's already provided by system

Comment: Bool has a method called toggle. `self.isSelected.toggle()`

Comment: Are you sure that if the user selects the cell the label color won't change? Note that the presence of a button there would be pointless

Comment: Nope, if he also allows cell selection this would not be an accurate answer, since it would be updated again. I just proposed this since the info he gave was just to change a textColor. To manage your problem and also selectedRow number then vadian solution is better :D

Comment: You mean his problem. Maybe OP added the button because he didn't know how to use the cell selected property.

Comment: Yes, I even thought about that, since most of beginners do that. I remember myself doing that in my beginnings.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the row number of the selected cell in the view controller.

Rather than modifying the color in the cell add a `callback` closure. In `cellForRow` handle the callback to set the current row to red and the previous row to black by reloading the row.

Something like this

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var selectedRow : Int?

    let data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier : "MyCell")
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.Label.textColor = indexPath.item == selectedRow ? .red : .black
        cell.callback = { [unowned self] in
            if let row = self.selectedRow { 
                self.selectedRow = indexPath.item
                collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(item: row, section: 0)])
            }
            cell.Label.textColor = .red
        }
        cell.Label.text = String(data[indexPath.row])
        return cell
     }
}

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    var callback : (() -> Void)?

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        callback?()
    }
}
```

Comment: I just copy your code paste it but it dose not work properly. build is success but button not turn black.